# free group acting on the 3D sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-groups

Let's say I have a 3 dimensional sphere $S^2$ and I define the following transformation $R_1$

- rotate the sphere around the north-south axis of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (north and south are fixed points till now)
- rotate a single, predetermined meridian (so a circle containing north and south) of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (no fixed points remain)

It seems to me that no point remains fixed and applying the mapping 4 times ${R_1}^4$ corresponds to the identity.

Why isn't the map $R_1$ - defined as the composition of the above two transformations -  acting freely on the sphere as the quotient group  $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

I know that it contradicts a well known theorem according to which only the antipodal mapping acts freely on $S^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem mentioned in the question is based on the invariant [degree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of a continuous mapping, but the second part of the mapping described in the question (i.e. rotating only a meridian of a sphere) is not a [continuous function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function_(topology)), indeed the following doesn't hold:

> A function between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is continuous if for every open set $V \subseteq Y$, the inverse image is an open subset of $X$

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a fixed point. One could demonstrate this with matrices, but I'll do a more geometric demonstration.

Let's imagine that the sphere is subdivided into three right-angled triangles by three great circles intersecting each other in six points, meeting at right angles. The six points are denoted $\pm A,\pm B,\pm C$ (think of $\pm A$ as the north-south poles, $\pm B$ as the east-west poles, and $\pm C$ as the front-back poles).

[The first image on this page](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/marusenko.htm) shows the subdivision that I have in mind.

Now I'll describe the rotations and their effect on the six poles.

The first rotation, around $\pm A$ by angle $\pi/2$, fixes $A$ and $-A$ and rotates the $B,C,-B,-C$ great circle, permuting those vertices in a 4-cycle $B \mapsto C \mapsto -B \mapsto -C \mapsto B$. Altogether the first rotation has the effect
\begin{align*} 
A &\mapsto A \\
-A &\mapsto -A \\
B &\mapsto C \\
-B &\mapsto -C \\
C &\mapsto -B \\
-C &\mapsto B
\end{align*}
The second rotation, around $\pm B$ by angle $\pi/2$, fixes $B$ and $-B$ and rottes the $A,C,-A,-C$ great circle, permuting those 4 vertices in a 4-cycle $A \mapsto C \mapsto -A \mapsto -C \mapsto A$, for the effect
\begin{align*}
A &\mapsto C \\
-A &\mapsto -C \\
B & \mapsto B \\
-B &\mapsto -B \\
C &\mapsto -A \\
-C &\mapsto A
\end{align*}
Now let's compose the first rotation followed by the second. The effect on the four vertices is this:
\begin{align*}
A &\mapsto C \\
-A &\mapsto -C \\
B &\mapsto -A \\
-B &\mapsto A \\
C &\mapsto -B \\
-C &\mapsto B
\end{align*}
The three great circles subdivide the sphere into three right-angled triangles, each of which has one vertex chosen from $\pm A$, another from $\pm B$, and the third from $\pm C$.

Consider the right angled triangle with vertices $A,C,-B$. It's three vertices are permuted in a 3-cycle $A \mapsto C \mapsto -B \mapsto A$, and so that triangle is rotated by angle $2\pi/3$, fixing the center of the triangle. So yes, there's a fixed point.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough in the description of the second rotation but what I meant to say was that the second is not a rotation of the whole sphere around an axis like the first one, but only the points of the great circle are rotating along that great circle. Imagine to colour in red the $\pm B$ great circle (meridian) on the sphere: the second rotation consists of rotating only that red circle

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "$\pm B$" great circle. My answer focusses on three great circles: the $A,B,-A,-C$ great circle around which the rotation fixes $\pm B$; the $B,C,-B,-C$ great circle around which the rotation fixes $\pm A$; and the $C,A,-C,-A$ great circle around which the rotation fixes $\pm B$. Does your "$\pm B$" great circle match one of those, or did you intend some entirely different great circle?

Comment: I added an link to an image in my answer, in order to aid visualization.

Comment: Also, I'll add that *every* rotation of the sphere has the effect of fixing an opposite pair of poles $P$ and $-P$, and rotating the great circle $E$ which is the "equator" with respect to $P$ and $-P$. The rotation goes through some angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. All of the parallel circles to $E$, centered on either $P$ or $-P$, are also rotated through that same angle $\theta$. So one can describe a general rotation in two ways: by specifing $\theta$ and the pair of fixed poles $\pm P$; or by specifying $\theta$ and the rotated great circle $E$.

Comment: We can change the wording of the second part of the mapping in my question in any way that is clearer and maybe it would be perfect to add a moving gif, that, at the moment, I'm not able to produce. Anyway the second part of the mapping is **not** a rotation of the sphere. Take the the $C, A,−C,−A$ great circle and think about it as a 2 dimensional circle and rotate only that 2 dimensional circle exactly like a 2 dimensional circle, while all the other points of the sphere (outside the plane of the great circle) stay fixed and don't move. Hope this clarify what I mean.

Comment: Ah hah. I have misunderstood your intent, and you have already answered your own question: your "counterexample" is discontinuous hence there is no contradiction.